# Xamarin forms layout initialisation issue

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm getting the following errors with my code

`LinearLayout selectMain = FindViewById<GridLayout>(Resource.Id.select);`

Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'Android.Widget.GridLayout' to 'Android.Widget.LinearLayout'

`GridLayout inputMain = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.input);`

Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'Android.Widget.LinearLayout' to 'Android.Widget.GridLayout'

this is confusing me because they are both the correct layout types, and if I swap the layout types in my code, it builds fine but when run it throws almost the same exemption.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) //run on startup.
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

    LinearLayout selectMain = FindViewById<GridLayout>(Resource.Id.select);
    GridLayout inputMain = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.input);
}
```

```
<GridLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:rowCount="9"
    android:id="@+id/input"
    tools:gridSpec="1|8|#0093eeff|K:#ee8700ff:16,l:72,l:16,r|S:#83ee00ff:16,0,l:16,0,r">

</GridLayout>
```

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/select">
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your types swapped.

```
LinearLayout selectMain = FindViewById<GridLayout>(Resource.Id.select);

GridLayout inputMain = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.input);
```

it should be:

```
//FindViewById<LinearLayout>
LinearLayout selectMain = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.select);

//FindViewById<GridLayout >
GridLayout inputMain = FindViewById<GridLayout>(Resource.Id.input);
```